# Sinónimo da meta-tag "tags-sinonimas" → "tags-sinónimas"

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags

Temos duas tags aqui no META uma com acentuação e a outra sem acentuação.

Penso que uma deveria ser sinónimo da outra, prevalecendo a que contém acentuação por ser português correto:

[tags-sinonimas](/questions/tagged/tags-sinonimas) → [tags-sinónimas](/questions/tagged/tags-sin%c3%b3nimas) ← [tags-sinonimas](/questions/tagged/tags-sinonimas)

**Nota:** Assumindo que no Brasil leva acento, caso não a tag principal pode ficar a que não tem acentuação.

Comment: No Brasil leva o circunflexo. Com a reforma ortográfica, não sei como ficou,se com circunflexo ou acento agudo – mas que tem acento, tem.

Comment: Aproveitando o tema, temos no momento dois sinônimos pendendo votos para aprovação pela comunidade. Quem quiser/puder votar, visite http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/vari%C3%A1veis/synonyms e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos/synonyms

Comment: @bfavaretto até onde me lembro fica o circunflexo.